# Postgres autovacuum high cpu/disk after database import

Tags: database, postgresql, postgresql-9.4, autovacuum

I have migrated a 2tb Postgres 9.4 database from one server to another, and after the import the autovacuum is going crazy with high cpu and disk for several days. The database has over 40,000 schemas/tables.

I have tried shutting down the database and restarting, but still high usage.
I have had issues with vacuum after imports before, it seems to be a common Postgres issue, is there any way to resolve it? The database that was exported was fine, no vacuum issues, it seems to be caused by the import.

I tried:

```
vacuumdb --all --full -w
```

But if failed to finish because of a statement timeout.
Other than disabling autovacuum, is there any solution?

[image: g]

Comment: What minor version of 9.4?

Comment: To me, "import" and "migrate" are different things.  Can you explain what you actually did?  Are you consolidating data from two different clusters into one cluster, using `pg_dump ...| psql ...` ?

Comment: "vacuumdb --all --full -w"  the --full option is almost certainly a mistake.

Comment: export from one database, pg_dumpall, and importing into another psql ...

Comment: so "vacuumdb --all -w" is better? why?

Comment: "so "vacuumdb --all -w" is better? why?"  It doesn't pointlessly rewrite the entire database.  You just wrote the thing with `psql -f ...`, why go through a rewrite it yet again using `vacuumdb --full`?

Answer (score 4):

Database have to re create statistics and visibility map after import. So it is expected behaviour. If you don't run `VACUUM` manually or autovacuum was disabled, then Postgres will not work effectively.

Export is a read operation, there is not need to do `VACUUM`. If you import 2TB data, then it is expected high CPU and IO until `VACUUM` is done. You can run `VACUUM` manually (with higher speed), but it should not fail because of timeouts (you should to increase timeouts).

Comment: Finally after the 4th day of vacuum trashing the disk/cpu it finally settled down. Note, I had to reboot the database each morning, otherwise it would remain high.

Comment: Is there a way for this to not take 4 days? is "vacuumdb --all --full -w" required?

Comment: @James - 4 days looks too long - maybe some is wrong - Postgres bug, too slow IO, too less memory, ... maybe 40 000 objects are problem for vacuumdb, maybe some system tables are bloated. The speed of VACUUM strongly depends on number of indexes. If you can reduce indexes, then you can decrease necessary time.